# Cómo puedo pasar una lista de objetos de una activity a otra?

Tags: java, android

me podrían decir de que manera pudo pasar una lista de objetos de una activity a otra.

Código Java:

```
List<Objeto> listaObjetos = new ArrayList();

Intent intent = new Intent(this,activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("listaObjetos",listaObjetos);
startActivity(intent);
```

De antemano gracias.

Comment: Erick, implementa la clase Parcelable en tu objeto y crea una Lista, para enviarla la lista usa el método putParcelableArrayList()  del bundle, me comentas que resultados tienes, revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma puede ser mediante la clase **[Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)** realizando un Intent y enviando los datos en el Bundle:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OtraActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("ListaObjetos", miListaDeObjetos);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Al recibirlo en la `Activity` sería de esta forma:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
ListObjetos = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("ListaObjetos");
```

Recuerda siempre, tu objeto debe implementar la clase **[Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)** :

```
public class miObjeto implements Parcelable{
...
...
...
```

Comment: Hola Elenasys primero que nada muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero me surgió un problema. Ya tengo mi clase con Parcelable pero al momento de recibir la lista y mostrar la información de algún objeto de la misma me da error, dice que existe un puntero nulo, creo que es la manera en la que lleno la información de cada objeto.    listaObjetos.add(new Objeto("información 1",""información 2)); será ese el problema o cómo debería de llenar cada objeto?

Comment: OK Erick, Agrega tu clase objeto en la pregunta por favor para tener más information.

Comment: Ya vi el error y fue al recibir la lista escribí mal la palabra clave para recibir, ya funciona al 100 muchas gracias

Comment: Excelente Erick, me da mucho gusto, saludos!

Comment: ¿no hay otra forma ?

Comment: @JhonJesus puedes guardarlo en prefetencias y usar Gson https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39254/se-puede-guardar-un-arraylist-de-objetos-en-sharedpreferences-y-después-leerlo

Comment: Hola @Elenasys, ya lo pase pero solo me pasa un objeto, por que sera?         . pasar lista de objetos y resultados a un activity  */
Bundle bund = new Bundle();ArrayList<Address> listas = listaAdrees; bund.putSerializable("faddress", listas); Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("listaaddress",bund); startActivity(intent);//recibir ArrayList<Address> lista = new ArrayList<>(); Bundle bund = new Bundle(); bund = getIntent().getBundleExtra("listaaddress");lista = (ArrayList<Address>) bund.getSerializable("faddress");

Comment: @JhonJesus tienes alguna pregunta sobre esto para ver a detalle, con gusto te ayudamos Jhon.

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma puede ser mediante serializable, le pasamos un bundle a la otra actividad,

```
  /*          pasar lista de objetos  a un activity  */
            //creamos un bundle
            Bundle bund = new Bundle();
           ArrayList<Address> listaAdress = new ArrayList<Address>;
            //guardamos en el bundle la lista
            bund.putSerializable("faddress",listaAdress);
             //le pasamos el bundle a la otra actividad
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("listaaddress",bund);
```

y si tenemos una lista y no un arraylist, los convertimos a arraylist y lo pasamos de la 
siguente forma:

```
List<Address> Listadress = null;
        Bundle bund = new Bundle();
            //convertimos la lista a arraylist
           ArrayList<Address> listaAdress = new ArrayList<Address>(Listadress);
           //guardamos el arraylist en el bundle 
            bund.putSerializable("faddress",listaAdress);
```

Para recibir el arraylist usamos el siguiente codigo

```
  /**                         Recibimos la lista en la otra actividad  **/
 ArrayList<Address> lista = new ArrayList<>();
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    //recuperamos el bundle
    bundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra("listaaddress");
    //recuperamos la lista del bundle
    lista = (ArrayList<Address>) bund.getSerializable("faddress");
```