# ¿Se puede guardar un ArrayList de objetos en SharedPreferences y después leerlo?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Los objetos tienen una variable String nombre y una variable de tipo int id. La idea es después mostrarlos en un ListView. Gracias!

Comment: Yo hago asi, primero convierto el objeto en json a la vez en string y asi de ese modo lo guardo como un campo string y despues lo vuelvo a obtener en json y sucesivamente en un objeto esto lo realizo con Jackson o Gson, puedes revisar el siguiente [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145606/how-android-sharedpreferences-save-store-object)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podría decir que nativamente no sería buena practica incluso guardar un objeto en preferencias, pero....

Afortunadamente ahora existe una librería proporcionada por Google, llamada **[Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)** con la cual puedes convertir un objeto a formato .json guardar un objeto en preferencias.

Un ejemplo:

```
 myObject myobjeto = new myObject();
 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
  .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
  Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
  Gson gson = new Gson();  //Instancia Gson.
  String json = gson.toJson(myobjeto); //convierte a .json el objeto
  prefs.putString("myObjeto", json);
  prefs.commit();
```

para obtener ese objeto:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
 Gson gson = new Gson(); //Instancia Gson.
 String json = prefs.getString("myObjeto", "");
 myObject myobjeto = gson.fromJson(json, myObject.class);
```

Ahora el ejemplo importante:

**Como guardar una lista de objetos en preferencias**:

```
//Suponiendo tener un Listado de objetos:
List<myObject> listObjetos;
//Crea un json a partir de la lista de objetos.
String jsonObjetos = new Gson().toJson(listObjetos);

//Crea preferencia
  SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
      .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
//Guarda lista de objetos, en formato .json
 prefs.putString("listObjetos", listObjetos);
 prefs.commit();
```

como obtener esa lista de objetos:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
 Gson gson = new Gson(); //Instancia Gson.
 //Obtiene datos (json)
 String objetos = prefs.getString("listObjetos", "");
 //Convierte json  a JsonArray.
String json = new Gson().toJson(objetos);
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

//Convierte JSONArray a Lista de Objetos!
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<myObject>>(){}.getType();
List<myObject> listObjetos = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, listType);
```

Comment: Está línea me da el error unhandle exception:
  JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

Comment: Revisa si el contenido de json es en realidad un json o tiene algún tipo de contenido.

Answer (score 1):

Añado información para completar la respuesta previa, la de Jorgesys, exactamente, añadiendo información sobre las SharedPreferences.

Las SharedPreferences funcionan igual que una tabla hash, almacenando por clave/valor. Estas son guardadas en un archivo XML en la carpeta de la aplicación dentro del dispositivo móvil.

La API de Andorid que debes usar es la [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Forma de trabajo:

- Tiene que usarse siempre el mismo nombre para acceder a las mismas
- Hay dos formas de acceso

  - getSharedPreferences(mode) y getSharedPreferences(name, mode)
- Hay tres modos de acceso:

  - Privado (Context.MODE_PRIVATE): Solo la aplicación o aplicaciones con el mismo User ID pueden acceder a estas
  - Leíble (Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE): Otras aplicaciones pueden leerlas. Muy peligroso
  - Escribible (Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE): Otras aplicaciones pueden editarlas. Muy peligroso
- Por seguridad, lo mejor es que las preferencias sean privadas. Los otros accesos no los recomienda Android.

Cómo guardar en ellas:

- Con el objeto SharedPreferences.Editor introducimos las preferencias
- Una vez introducidas, hay que guardarlas usando el método commit()
- Se pueden guardar objetos Set desde la API 11

  ```
  SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedpreferences("Ejemplo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
  editor.putBoolean("registrado", true);
  ```

Cómo cargar de ellas:

- Para cargar las preferencias tenemos que usar el mismo nombre que usamos al guardarlas
- El segundo parámetro indica el valor por defecto que toma el campo si la preferencia no existe

  ```
  SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedpreferences("Ejemplo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  boolean registrado = preferences.getBoolean("registrado", true);
  ```