# Android Studio- guardar objeto en sharedPreferences

Tags: android-studio, sharedpreferences

Quiero guardar un objeto en sharedPreferences pero no se como se hace. ¿ Alguien me podría orientar con un ejemplo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las SharedPreferences funcionan igual que una tabla hash, almacenando por clave/valor. Estas son guardadas en un archivo XML en la carpeta de la aplicación dentro del dispositivo móvil.

La API de Andorid que debes usar es la [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Forma de trabajo:

- Tiene que usarse siempre el mismo nombre para acceder a las mismas
- Hay dos formas de acceso

  - getSharedPreferences(mode) y getSharedPreferences(name, mode)
- Hay tres modos de acceso:

  - Privado (Context.MODE_PRIVATE): Solo la aplicación o aplicaciones con el mismo User ID pueden acceder a estas
  - Leíble (Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE): Otras aplicaciones pueden leerlas. Muy peligroso
  - Escribible (Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE): Otras aplicaciones pueden editarlas. Muy peligroso
- Por seguridad, lo mejor es que las preferencias sean privadas. Los otros accesos no los recomienda Android.

Cómo guardar en ellas:

- Con el objeto SharedPreferences.Editor introducimos las preferencias
- Una vez introducidas, hay que guardarlas usando el método commit()
- Se pueden guardar objetos Set desde la API 11

  ```
  SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedpreferences("Ejemplo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
  editor.putBoolean("registrado", true);
  ```

Cómo cargar de ellas:

- Para cargar las preferencias tenemos que usar el mismo nombre que usamos al guardarlas
- El segundo parámetro indica el valor por defecto que toma el campo si la preferencia no existe

  ```
  SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedpreferences("Ejemplo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  boolean registrado = preferences.getBoolean("registrado", true);
  ```

Comment: Quizás deberías publicarlo como respuesta a [¿Se puede guardar un ArrayList de objetos en SharedPreferences y después leerlo?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/39254/127)

Comment: Ok, ya la he añadida como complemento de la respuiesta anterior. Gracias @Mariano por indicarme esa pregunta que desconocía.