# ¿Como llenar un array desde otro activity?

Tags: android

Buenas A todos, quiero saber como puedo llenar un array de objetos desde otro activity enviale la información, y se vea en otro activity cuando se ejecute.

La idea es como un select de productos, tengo creada una clase productor, un adapter de extends ArrayAdapter, algo como una variable global que pueda llenar desde otro actiity.

Answer (score 1):

Tu clase productor debería implementar la interfaz Parcelable, y luego enviarlos a través del Intent con el que llamas a tu nuevo Activity

```
Intent i = new Intent();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putParcelableArrayList("productores",(ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) ProductoresArray);

i.putExtras(b);
i.setClass(Productor.this);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Te refieres a un `Array` (y no a un `List`) esta es la solución:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArray("arrayDatos", new String[]{valor1, valor2});
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityDestino.Class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

en la `Activity` destino recibirías el `bundle` conteniendo el `Array` de esta forma:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] arrayDatos = b.getStringArray("arrayDatos");
```

---

Si deseas enviar una Lista de objetos sería de esta forma:

[Cómo puedo pasar una lista de objetos de una activity a otra?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/19912/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-pasar-una-lista-de-objetos-de-una-activity-a-otra/19914#19914)

Comment: Si en realidad es un lista de objetos, tengo un activity A, que con un boton llama a la lista de productos- Activity B, selecciona un producto, agregar la cantidad y al poner ok deberia agregar a un lista de objetos y mostrar el activity A inicial, con el list view actualizado