# Llenar una lista desde una otra activity

Tags: android

Estoy leyendo una JSON desde la web, Después  de parsear mi JSON ,he cargado los datos en un arreglo para poder usarlos, mi pregunta es, como puedo pasar dichos datos en otra activity para llenar una lista ..

mi código..

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    String url = "http://www.air-intra.com/apps/air-app/agregar.php?token=" + dato + "&codiart=" + cod + "";
                    HttpHandler she = new HttpHandler();
                    JSONObject jsonStr = she.makeServiceCall(url);

                    Log.e("CODEXES", String.valueOf(jsonStr));
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(jsonStr));
                        JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("PRR");
                      //  prod.clear();
                        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                            String codig = c.getString("codigo");
                            String des = c.getString("descrip");
                            String prec = c.getString("precio");
                            String reglon = c.getString("renglon");

                            HashMap<String, String> contacto = new HashMap<>();
                            contacto.put("codigo", codig);
                            contacto.put("descrip", des);
                            contacto.put("precio", prec);
                            contacto.put("renglon", reglon);
                          //  reg = "" + reglon;
                            productos.add(contacto);





                    } }catch(JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

y en el onPostExecute quiero mandar los datos del arreglo en una lista de la otra activity

```
 @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

                   // Log.d("RESULTADO", toString());
                    Intent intent = new Intent(busqueda.this,Carrito.class);
```

// Que puedo hacer ...

```
startActivity(intent);
                    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                }
```

Comment: Buenas compañero @Wid_Maer lo que estas queriendo enviar a la actividad `Carrito.class` es un `array` o una `arraylist` llamada `productos` o quieres enviar tu `JSONArray` ?

Comment: Gracias @Nicethunder.. es un arraylist.. quiero enviar al carrito.class los datos del JSONArray ..

Comment: si lo que buscas pasar es el `JSONArray` puedes leer la segunda respuesta de este post [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686531/passing-jsonarray-from-1-activity-to-another) pero si es una lista tambien puede mirar la respuesta de Jorgesys de este otro post [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/19912/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-pasar-una-lista-de-objetos-de-una-activity-a-otra)

Answer (score 0):

Primero te recomendaria el uso de [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) que hace el trabajo de realizar las consultas a endpoint con una sintaxis mas sencilla y te da ayuda a obtener mas informacion sobre la respuesta del servidor, por ejemplo: 404, 500, entre otras..

Respondiendo a tu pregunta sobre como pasar la informacion de una activity a otra tenemos la opcion de enviar estos mediante los extra en el intent.

Desde tu Activity:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(busqueda.this,Carrito.class);

    intent.putExtra("string","hola mundo!");
    intent.putExtra("entero",0);
    intent.putExtra("real",0.5f);
    intent.putExtra("boolean", true);

    startActivity(intent);
```

y Recibiendolo de esta forma en el `onCreate` del otro Activity Carrito de esta forma:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String string = intent.getStringExtra("string");
    //el segundo parametro es un default para la variable
    //en caso que no encuentre la variable
    int entero = intent.getIntExtra("entero",0);
    float real = intent.getFloatExtra("real",0.0f);
    boolean bool = intent.getBooleanExtra("bool", false);
```

En el caso de enviar datos no primitivos tenemos la opcion de hacer que estos sean Parcelable o Serializable.

Los 2 cumplen una misma funcion solo que el parcelable tienes que escribir un poco mas, te dejo un ejemplo [aquí](http://androcode.es/2012/12/trabajando-con-parcelables/) y Serializable es mas facil de implementar pero un poco mas ineficiente que Parcelable, ejemplo de Serializable [aquí](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/07/25/serialization-android-simple-example/).

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Gracias @Dorianalexis... pasr los datos en la otra si lo hice mi duda es almacenando los datos en la llista  de la otra activity...Seria eligir items de una lista y pasarlos en otra lista en otra activity.. 
Espere que me exprese bien...

Comment: por lo que habia entendido de la pregunta inicial era pasar datos de un activity a otro.

Si quieres pasar elementos que estén seleccionados puedes tener una estructura que te deje agregarle un campo boolean y antes de pasar al siguiente activity pasas los seleccionados a una estructura limpia y lo envías al otro activity.

Comment: a que te referis cuando decis una estructura limpia?

Comment: @WidMaer instancias un nuevo objecto, un arraylist, un array, jsonArray, etc...

Seria instanciar un object de esa estructura y solo agregar los elementos que sean seleccionados.